# reverse engineering tool for ETL

Tags: reverse-engineering, epsilon

How can I get `model` from `transformation code` that write with `Epsilon Transformation Language (ETL)`? Is there any `tool` about it?

Comment: As far as I can remember, the question was asked on the EMF Epsilon forums ~2 years ago and the answer was negative - there is no official meta-model behind ETL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `Epsilon Haetae` [1] we can obtain models from ETL programs.

[1]. https://github.com/epsilonlabs/haetae